# How to Generate Exe File after Getting Input from User C#

Tags: c#

i just want to know how to generate or build executable .exe after getting user input data in c#.

suppose in c# app .
textBox2 Name :Alex
textBox2 Mobile :01010101111
textBox3 School :St George

in below a Button called [Generate EXE].
when i click on [Generate EXE].
a exe file generated and when any one click on that exe file.
a message show ur name is Alex and Your Mobile name is 01010101111 & ans your school is St George in console.

Thanks /Please help me.

Comment: Be aware that normally you cannot edit the exe file you're currently running, so you need another application that is embedded as a resource to extract and "patch" the entered data into.

Answer (score 2):

I have a interesting method for such cases. **I know it's wrong but works (just for laziness)**. Just append your data to your EXE file and in in your application, open itself and read last X bytes (you decide the X)

```
// to embed in exe
byte[] buffer = new byte[5];
buffer[0] = (byte)'h';
buffer[0] = (byte)'e';
buffer[0] = (byte)'l';
buffer[0] = (byte)'l';
buffer[0] = (byte)'o';
FileStream fs = new FileStream("c:\\a.exe", FileMode.Append);
fs.Write(buffer, 0, 5);
fs.Close();

// to extract at runtime
byte[] buffer = new byte[5];
FileStream fs = new FileStream(Application.StartupPath + "\\" +
                                System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName,
                                FileMode.Open);
fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
fs.Seek(-5, SeekOrigin.Current);
fs.Read(buffer, 0, 5);
fs.Close();
```

Comment: That's really fascinating that it is okay to do that. I figured that adding data to an exe would create an invalid checksum of some kind.

Comment: @DanDrews: It would break the signature of an exe, but if you're not testing that, no one does. This has been a very common practice for a long time (i.e. self-extracting zips or single-file-installers work like this).

Comment: @BinTrap don't be so lazy and write some code.

Comment: bro i dont know how to save as .exe in c# ...
i make form application in c# but i don't know how to build or save as .exe

Comment: @BinTrap you don't know how to open/write/close a file?

Comment: @BinTrap read my updated answer for code. I didn't tested it but works well. Checksum won't be a problem by the way.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/d0d6oew63/
snapshot link above.
snapshot.when i click on generate exe a exe file build and when anyone click on that exe message show info.
@Mustafa

Comment: Ok, you can do it with all the info I gave you.